# How to implement send email functionality in google app engine django non-rel project

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, email

I am trying to send email in my django non-rel gae project.

I  tried by using django's send_mail method and also by google appengine's mail method(from google.appengine.api import mail).

But both time it gives unauthorized sender error on gae server.

my email sending code is like this.

```
            message = mail.EmailMessage()
            message.sender = "The example team <xxxxxx@example.com>"
            message.to = "username@example.com"
            message.body = "welcome"
            message.send()
```

Anyone know how can i send email? Which settings i have to do with my application? Please answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the sender email address should be the admin of the google app engine application. Make sure you are using the correct email address

Comment: Oh, It works. I have set sender email as 
abcd@example.com  where example.com is my mistake. I have to set gmail.com.
Thanks.